# Draggable interaction not working on cellphone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-draggable

I am currently working on a project with jquery mobile and I made a div draggable. The drag interaction works perfectly until I open the website on my Samsung S3 mini.

This is my head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/florida_tech.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>`
```

This is the script for the drag interaction:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
    });
</script>
```

The div I am moving has ID = DRAGGABLE:

```
<div data-role="content" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px">
      <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="position:relative; height: 347px">
          <div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px"> 
                <img src="style/pic.png" alt="Parking Lot Map"/>             
          </div>
          <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 81px "> &nbsp </div>
          <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 102px "> &nbsp </div>

      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily fixed.

Only thing you need to do is to include some additional javascript. It will extend classic **`jQuery`** implementation of touch events. I am talking this from my past experience with this problem and it can be tested on this **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zeXuM/

Include this javascript in your code and it should work:

```
    // This is a fix for mobile devices

/iPad|iPhone|Android/.test( navigator.userAgent ) && (function( $ ) {

var proto =  $.ui.mouse.prototype,
_mouseInit = proto._mouseInit;

$.extend( proto, {
    _mouseInit: function() {
        this.element
        .bind( "touchstart." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchStart" ) );
        _mouseInit.apply( this, arguments );
    },

    _touchStart: function( event ) {
         this.element
        .bind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchMove" ) )
        .bind( "touchend." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchEnd" ) );

        this._modifyEvent( event );

        $( document ).trigger($.Event("mouseup")); //reset mouseHandled flag in ui.mouse
        this._mouseDown( event );

        //return false;           
    },

    _touchMove: function( event ) {
        this._modifyEvent( event );
        this._mouseMove( event );   
    },

    _touchEnd: function( event ) {
        this.element
        .unbind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName )
        .unbind( "touchend." + this.widgetName );
        this._mouseUp( event ); 
    },

    _modifyEvent: function( event ) {
        event.which = 1;
        var target = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
        event.pageX = target.clientX;
        event.pageY = target.clientY;
    }

});

})( jQuery );
```

Original author of a touchFix plugin used in this example is [Oleg Slobodskoi](https://github.com/kof).

Comment: what if I dont want the div to return to its original place. I just want to make it draggable. I have read thru the code but I could not figure out how to make it just drag.

Answer (score 0):

yeah， Gajotres has given a great answer, but if you want to deal with click and move event at the same time, the code may be like this:

```js
// This is a fix for mobile devices
var moveFlag = 0;

/iPad|iPhone|Android/.test( navigator.userAgent ) && (function( $ ) {
 var proto =  $.ui.mouse.prototype,
 _mouseInit = proto._mouseInit;
 $.extend( proto, {
     _mouseInit: function() {
         this.element
         .bind( "touchstart." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchStart" ) );
         _mouseInit.apply( this, arguments );
     },
     _touchStart: function( event ) {
          this.element
         .bind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchMove" ) )
         .bind( "touchend." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchEnd" ) );

         this._modifyEvent( event );

         $( document ).trigger($.Event("mouseup")); //reset mouseHandled flag in ui.mouse
         this._mouseDown( event );

         //return false;           
     },
     _touchMove: function( event ) {
      moveFlag = 1;
         this._modifyEvent( event );
         this._mouseMove( event );   

     },
     _touchEnd: function( event ) {
         // dispatch the click event
         if (moveFlag == 0) {
              var evt = document.createEvent('Event'); 
      evt.initEvent('click',true,true); 
                    this.handleElement[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
         };
         
         this.element
         .unbind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName )
         .unbind( "touchend." + this.widgetName );
         this._mouseUp( event ); 

      moveFlag = 0;
     },
     _modifyEvent: function( event ) {
         event.which = 1;
         var target = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
         event.pageX = target.clientX;
         event.pageY = target.clientY;
     }
 });
})( jQuery );
```